# UITableView cell is displaying an incorrect image, even while setting the image to nil as the first step in tableView.dequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to do something very basic, but the fix proposed in other similar questions does not seem to be working. I have an image cache, and a tableView. I want to display the image from the cache if it exists, otherwise there should be nothing. For some reason the tableView is still displaying a reused cell with the wrong image, even when I set the image view to nil. Below is my code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchResultsTableViewCell

    cell.profilePhoto?.image = nil
    cell.profilePhoto?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    if let userID = myObject.posterId, let profileImage = self.imageCache.object(forKey: userID as AnyObject) {
        cell.profilePhoto?.image = profileImage
    } else {
        if let userId = myObject.posterId {
            downloadImage.beginImageDownload() {
                (imageOptional) in
                if let image = imageOptional {
                    cell.profilePhoto?.image = image
                    self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: userId as AnyObject)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't for the life of me figure out why the image is not being set to nil, even though I do that as the first step!

Comment: setting image to nil is not enough. You should also cancel loading image before cell is being reused.

Comment: I recommend you to use Kingfisher to download image.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `downloadImage.beginImageDownload` closures are holding references to the uitableview cells.

When you complete the image download, you set `cell.profilePhoto?.image` property, even if the tableView recycles reusable cells to display a different row.

Assign your cell's `tag` to the `indexPath.row` and test if cell is still relevant for assigning downloaded image:

```
/* right after cell dequeue */
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

then

```
/* download finished here */
if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
    /* yeah, I want to rock this cell with my downloaded image! */
    cell.profilePhoto?.image = downloadedImage
}
```

*Be aware: this will only work in tableview with one section.*

P.S. You can place the `clean up` of your cells in `prepareForReuse` method inside the SearchResultsTableViewCell to tidy things a little.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be setting your image to `nil` but have you considered the downloads which might be in flight when you reuse that cell? It looks like you could be updating a cell's image when the download for some previous index path finishes.