# TableViewCells Incorrectly Loading Correct Image Based on Firebase Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

Building a news feed and the user has the option to either like or dislike a post. When this event occurs, the color of the like image changes accordingly. The code is correct and all of the backend data is working (IE: The values of likes/dislikes updates correctly). The problem is that when I like or dislike a post, all other like/dislike images change color and incorrectly display the corresponding images. Here is the code inside the **tableviewcell** and **cellforrowat**:

**TableViewCell**

```
func configureCell(post: Post) {
    self.post = post

    likesRef = FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_LIKES_REF.child(self.post.postID)
    dislikeRef = FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_DISLIKES_REF.child(self.post.postID)

    FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_LIKES_REF.child(post.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull{
            self.likesImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gray_fire")
        } else {
            self.likesImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trending_fire")
        }
    })

    FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_DISLIKES_REF.child(post.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            self.dislikeImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "upsidedownGrayFire")
        } else {
            self.dislikeImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueFire")
        }
    })
}
```

**In Event of a Like**

```
func likeTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    FriendSystem.system.loadUserFriends(post.userID)
    if FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.child(post.userID).key == FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_ID {
        return
    } else {
        likesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
                self.dislikeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                    if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
                        self.likesImage.image = UIImage(named: "trending_fire")
                        self.dislikeImage.image = UIImage(named: "upsidedownGrayFire")
                        self.currentUser.adjustScore(addScore: true)
                        FriendSystem.system.postUsersFriends.forEach({ (key) in
                            self.post.adjustUserLikes(key: key, addLike: true)
                        })
                        self.likesRef.setValue(true)

                    } else {
                        self.likesImage.image = UIImage(named: "gray_fire")
                        self.dislikeImage.image = UIImage(named: "upsidedownGrayFire")
                        self.currentUser.adjustScore(addScore: true)
                        FriendSystem.system.postUsersFriends.forEach({ (key) in
                            self.post.adjustUserLikes(key: key, addLike: true)

                        })
                        self.dislikeRef.removeValue()

                    }

                })

            } else {
                self.likesImage.image = UIImage(named: "gray_fire") // Change the image
                self.dislikeImage.image = UIImage(named: "upsidedownGrayFire")
                self.currentUser.adjustScore(addScore: false)
                FriendSystem.system.postUsersFriends.forEach({ (key) in
                    self.post.adjustUserLikes(key: key, addLike: false) // Remove the like

                })
                self.likesRef.removeValue() // removes the value to false in the DB

            }
        })
    }
}
```

**CellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = FriendSystem.system.friendPosts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell") as? FriendPostCell {

        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I have been stuck on this for about a week and am considering dropping the concept all together. Any help would be appreciated. Also, if there is a extra or missing closure, it was cause I edited the real code to show the problem.

Comment: guess this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916316/uitableview-cell-is-displaying-an-incorrect-image-even-while-setting-the-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues with "likes" and Firebase. I can't speak to your specific issue as you are using a `tapGestureRecognizer` and I'm not sure where that's applied. I can however, show you how I resolved my issues and perhaps we can share some code to help resolve this issue.

If I had to take a guess I'd say your problem in in this method:

```
func configureCell(post: Post) {
    self.post = post

    likesRef = FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_LIKES_REF.child(self.post.postID)
    dislikeRef = FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_DISLIKES_REF.child(self.post.postID)

    FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_LIKES_REF.child(post.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull{
            self.likesImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gray_fire")
        } else {
            self.likesImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trending_fire")
        }
    })

    FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_DISLIKES_REF.child(post.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            self.dislikeImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "upsidedownGrayFire")
        } else {
            self.dislikeImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueFire")
        }
    })
```

The reason I suspect this is the issues is due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase. The query takes time and when the result is returned and applied to that cell it might have be reused if the user scrolled. Which means the wrong cell image gets changed.

First I'd recommend that every post has a value "userLiked" that determines what image to display. In my case I am changing the which like button is displayed.

In cellForRowAt you check something like this:

```
if dataSource[indexPath.row]!.userLiked == nil {
      DatabaseFunctions.userLiked(postID: key, cell: cell)
}
```

userLiked checks if that user has previously liked that post, updates the locally stored value post.userLiked and updates the cell image.

Here is how I am achieving this:

```
static func userLiked(postID: String, cell: BetterPostCell) {
        let likeRef = Database.database().reference()
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            likeRef.child("userActivity").child(uid).child("likes").child(postID).queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
                if snap.exists() {
                    cell.helpfulButton.isHidden = true
                    cell.notHelpfulButton.isHidden = false
                    postDict[postID]?.userLiked = true

                }
                else {
                    postDict[postID]?.userLiked = false
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank your for your response. This insight actually led me to solving the problem but I did it with a little less code. Your idea of creating a data attribute of userLiked -> Bool solved my issues. Essentially, instead of having to check firebase node I was able to check the post class and adjust the image accordingly. From there, all I had to do was change the values of Bool when the image was tapped. Thank your for commenting, this was great!